# Code to create a security token isn't working

Tags: forms-authentication, security-token-service

I've been developing a SharePoint Server 2010 site, which uses Forms Based Authentication. As part of my custom login script, I used the following C# code:

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken token = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url), Membership.Providers["FBAMembershipProvider"].Name, Roles.Providers["FBARoleProvider"].Name, FBAUserName, FBAPassword);
SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(token);
```

On my dev server it works just fine, creating the appropriate token and allowing a user to be logged in with FBA.

However, I'm now transferring all my code to a new SharePoint Server 2010 server, and the code above isn't working. The first line returns a token with a null value.

Can anyone help me understand why?

In the back of my mind I'm thinking that I need to install something on the new server, but I can't for the life of me remember what it is. Something like ADSF, or similar acronym. I check the Control Panel > Programs and Features on the old server, but couldn't see anything that might be relevant.

Any ideas?

[update] Following Anders Rask's request for the ULS logs, I think I found the cause of my issue. Now I need to find the solution (I think I've seen this before)

```
10/18/2011 22:07:24.65  w3wp.exe (0x0968)                           0x0758  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           0000    Unexpected  Password check on 'mytest@email.com' generated exception: 'System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: You must specify a non-autogenerated machine key to store passwords in the encrypted format. Either specify a different passwordFormat, or change the machineKey configuration to use a non-autogenerated decryption key.     at System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.EncryptPassword(Byte[] password)     at System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.EncodePassword(String pass, Int32 passwordFormat, String salt)     at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat)     at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, Str...    
10/18/2011 22:07:24.65* w3wp.exe (0x0968)                           0x0758  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           0000    Unexpected  ...ing password)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFormsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)'.  
10/18/2011 22:07:24.65  w3wp.exe (0x0968)                           0x0758  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           fo1t    Monitorable SPSecurityTokenService.Issue() failed: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.FailedAuthenticationException]: The security token username and password could not be validated. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.FailedAuthenticationException: The security token username and password could not be validated.).   
10/18/2011 22:07:24.66  w3wp.exe (0x0E00)                           0x11DC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           fsq7    High        Request for security token failed with exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The security token username and password could not be validated.     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.ReadResponse(Message response)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo)  4acf80d8-9c59-457f-a859-60f8a9af6d46
10/18/2011 22:07:24.66  w3wp.exe (0x0E00)                           0x11DC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           8306    Critical    An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The security token username and password could not be validated..    4acf80d8-9c59-457f-a859-60f8a9af6d46
```

Comment: I take it that you remembered to provision web.config changes to the new site? (membership and roleprovider settings)

Comment: Yeah, I followed [Donal Conlon's guide to configuring FBA](http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/configuring-forms-base-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-using-iis7/), as I'd done on the old server, and updated the 3 web.configs (Central Admin, Security Store Web Service, my Web Application). I checked them again, and as far as I can see, they are all correct.

Comment: please add relevant errors and ULS logs

Comment: In order to get more characters for the log entries, I updated my original question, above. Thank you for suggesting the logs.. I wasn't expecting it to be there (but now I know EVERY error goes there), and I think I located the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah i have seen this before as well, and it has hit me in production as well ;-)

Are you using ProtectedData in .NET to encrypt passwords? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.unprotect.aspx

my guess is that you are seeing this now because your production environment is multi-server, and your development environment is single server. Encryption works fine with machine key as long as you are on a single server, but it breaks when you run on several servers.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but for me it was simply that my SecurityTokenServiceApplication web.config was using an auto-generated machinecode, while the SharePoint web application was using a specified one. Once I copied the specified machinecode to the STSA, everything worked. I think I'll still be using a single server setup when I finally move into production, but if that changes then your answer will be 110% correct :) Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @QMKevin worked for me too. STSA machine key was the issue. Thanks :)